# Axios get function returns a promise in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I tried fetching data from a giphy api using the following function and print the returned value to the browser console.

```
const fetchData = (url) =>
  {
    return axios.get(url).then(res => res.data.data);
  }

  const data = fetchData(giphy_url);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
```

But on printing the value of the `data` variable, it prints:

```
Data: [object Promise]
```

I want the data in the response to be accessed.
Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: `async.. await`?

Comment: You're missing await call to be able to use results of promise synchronously:
await fetchData(giphy_url);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axios API calls return a Promise object. From Axios [documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro), "Axios is a **promise-based** HTTP Client for node.js and the browser."

You would need to await on a promise object to access the response value. Note that in order to use `await` keyword in your function, you would need to mark it as `async`. Do something like below.

```
const fetchData = async(url) =>
  {
    return await axios.get(url).then(res => res.data.data);
  }

  const data = fetchData(giphy_url);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

It happend because javascript is a non blocking language and axios' get function is a promise function. So when you print your data variable which is not fill yet, you should use it like this.

```
const fetchData = async (url) =>
  {
    return axios.get(url).then(res => res.data.data);
  }

// careful that when you want to use await it should be on async function
  const data = await fetchData(giphy_url);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);

  // or 
  fetchData(giphy_url).then((data)=>{
    console.log(`Data: ${data}`);

  })
```

Comment: I edited your post, you should use `await` into your `async` function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async/await` to get `data`:

```
const yourFunction = async () => {
  const data = await fetchData(giphy_url);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are handling axios in wrong way

```
const fetchData = async (url) =>{
   return await axios.get(url);
}

const data = fetchData(giphy_url);
console.log(`Data: ${data}`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `async-await` concept as below:

```
const fetchData = (url) => {
  return axios.get(url);
}

const getData = async () => {
  const data = await fetchData(giphy_url);
  console.log(`Data: ${data}`);
}

getData();
```